# redis RESTORE command not working as expected

Tags: redis

Redis doc says

> "RESTORE checks the RDB version and data checksum. If they don't match
>   an error is returned."

But i dont see any errors when i restored a key, like below.
Before starting i noted down the dump values of two strings which are shown below

sat - `\x00\x03sat\x06\x00a_\xfd<\x8eN\xbf\xf2`

dfd - `\x00\x03dfd\x06\x00\x0b\xcf@\x12BBso`

Then i did

```
set b sat
del b
restore b 0 "\x00\x03dfd\x06\x00\x0b\xcf@\x12BBso"
```

In the first line of the above code the value of `b` is set to 'sat', but in the third line im restoring `b` with the dump value of 'dfd'. I expected an error, as mentioned in the RESTORE docs. Why is restore successful here?

Answer (score 0):

Really interesting question, I've never reasoned about that part of the doc.
I think that the checks are:

1. Check to see if the RDB version of the data to be restored is the same as the running server (I mean the version of the RDB format)
2. The data to be restored have a valid checksum

So the check is not performed on the previous value stored on the last RDB snapshot available.